# Any code can trigger a batching override action?

Tags: biztalk

I am working on a project which will batching some 834 records in file.

I setup the batching trigger as when the record count reaches a number, a batch file will release. But I also want release a batch even the record count is not reached (for example, every night, release all queueing record as a final file).

I know it can be done by click the override button in Batch Configuration window, but it need be done automatically.

So, basically, my question is, what did BizTalk do when I clicked the override button? Does BizTalk prove anyway to let me do that in a program?

I must say I did not try to send a controlmessage to a batch setting as release per record count, if you know this works, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there and to complete the process isn't that difficult.

Leave the Batch configuration at the records count as it is.

Then, setup a process where an External Release trigger is sent at the appropriate time.  A Windows Scheduled Task is a viable option, it can copy a file to a File Receive Location.

This article describes how to create the trigger message: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb246108.aspx

Comment: I saw this article.  but statement in this article says "To enable the external release trigger, you must select the External release trigger property in the Batch Configuration page of the Agreement Properties dialog box for either X12 or EDIFACT. This property indicates that an external release message is required for batch release. "
It sounds like only when "External release trigger" was set, the controlmessage will work. That's why i did not try it.

Comment: I see how that could be a bit misleading, but the External Release message will always work.  That's actually how the Override button works.  Hint: The Override button is an easy way to get a valid release message for that batch.  Turn on Message Tracking on the BatchControlMessageRecvPort Receive Port.  Override the batch, then save the override message from Tracking.  Then turn off message body tracking.